# Confusion about probability densities of the MB Distribution

Tags: thermodynamics, particle-physics, probability

The probability of a particle being at speed $v$ or its corresponding energy $E$ via the MB Distribution $f(v)$ and $f(E)$ is
$$f(v)\cdot dv=f(E)\cdot dE$$
To make this equation valid, either the $dE$ must correspond to a fixed $dv$ or vice versa according to $E = \frac{1}{2}mv^2$
$$f(v)\cdot dv = f(E)\cdot mv\cdot dv$$
$$or$$
$$f(v)\cdot \frac{dE}{\sqrt{2mE}}= f(E)\cdot dE$$
Because of these two versions, there are 2 ways to get back to the MB Distribution which is a probability *density*.

1. Divide $f(v)dv$ by a fixed $dv$ and therefore divide $f(E)dE$ by the corresponding varying $dE = mv\cdot dv$
2. Divide the $f(E)dE$ by a fixed $dE$ and therefore divide $f(v)dv$ by the corresponding varying $dv = \frac{dE}{\sqrt{2mE}}$

For *the same* $v$, the emerged $f(v)$ from method 1 gives a different probability density than the emerged $f(v)$ from method 2. Idem for $f(E)$ for the same $E$.

So if I have $f(v)$ in front of me without knowing whether it was deduced from method **1** or **2**, how do I know whether I should multiply it by a fixed $dv$ or a varying $dv = \frac{dE}{\sqrt{2mE}}$ to get the correct probabilities again?

Answer (score 0):

> the MB Distribution $f(v)$ and $f(E)$ is
> $$f(v)\cdot dv=f(E)\cdot dE$$

The two $f()$ functions are not the same. Not sure if you mean this to be understood implicitly, or what. The functional form of the function being integrated (your $f$) *changes* in the way shown below. The integration limits can change too generally, but might not change in some specific cases.

To account for these changes, I think it is clearer to write something like:
$$
\int_{v_1}^{v_2} f(v) dv = \int_{E(v_1)}^{E(v_2)} f(v(E)) \frac{dv}{dE}dE\;,
$$
where, we just change variables from $v$ to $E$ as usual, based on the functional relationship between $v$ and $E$: $v(E) = \sqrt{2mE}$.

From the above, we see that the thing you called "$f(E)$" should really have been called some other name like $g(E)$, where $g(E) = f(v(E))\frac{dv}{dE}$.

> Because of these two versions, there are 2 ways to get back to the MB Distribution which is a probability *density*.

No, there's only one correct way to do this. You don't get two different results, unless one of the results is wrong. What you are doing should be just the usual change of variables, which is well known for hundreds of years from integral calculus.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. So are you saying that $$\frac{P(E+dE)−P(E)}{dE}=\frac{P(E+mvdv)−P(E)}{mvdv}$$ and that $$\frac{P(v+dv)+P(v)}{dv}=\frac{P(v+\frac{dE}{\sqrt{2mE}})-P(v)}{\frac{dE}{\sqrt{2mE}}}$$ Even when $dE$ and $dv$ are constants and $P(x)$ is _not_ proportional to $x$?

Comment: Could you please verify my above statement? If the equations are valid, is there a way to analytically conclude this? Because if $y$ changes drastically with very small $x$ changes, how can derivatives based on 2 different interval sizes still give the same derivative?

Answer (score 0):

The real question is about probability densities and change of variables.

If $x$ is a variable with probability density $f(x)$ and $z=z(x)$ is some monotonic function of $x$, then $z$ is distributed with probability density $h(z)$ and the two distributions satisfy
$$ 
   f(x) dx = h(z) dz
$$
This has a simple meaning: the number of points between $x$ and $x+dx$ is exactly the same as between $z$ and $z+dz$, because the two intervals bracket the same region, only in terms of different variables. In writing this equation we use different symbols for the distribution of energy $(f)$ and the distribution of velocities $(h)$ because they are different functions of their respective arguments.

**Application to MB Distribution** With $x=v$, then
$$
   \boxed{
   f(v) = 4\pi v^2\left(\frac{m}{2 kT}\right)^{3/2} e^{-m v^2/k T}
   }
$$
The MB energy distribution is
$$
  h(E) = f(v) \frac{dv}{dE}
$$
Using
$$
  z = E= \frac{m v^2}{2},\quad
  v=(2E/m)^{1/2},\quad
  \frac{dv}{dE} = (2mE)^{-1/2}
$$
and after substitutions
$$
  \boxed{
  h(E) = 2\left(\frac{E}{\pi k T}\right)^{1/2}
         \frac{e^{-E/k T}}{k T}
  }
$$

Comment: Thanks, one question though. Is this equation correct? 
$$h(E)dE=f(v)dv$$
If yes, then I'm having trouble with it. Because it should be rewritten depending on which of the two intervals you're basing it on. If you're fixing $dE$ then the corresponding interval in terms of $v$ would be $dv=\frac{dE}{(2mE)^{1/2}}$ thus$$h(E)dE=f(v)\frac{dE}{(2mE)^{1/2}}$$ And if you're basing it on a fixed $dv$, then:
$$h(E)mvdv=f(v)dv$$
Only then would both equations have the exact number of points because the intervals correspond. So how exactly is $h(E)dE=f(v)dv$ valid if the intervals differ?

Comment: @Phy  Yes, the equation you wrote is correct, because: $E$ is the energy that corresponds to $v$ and $E+dE$ is the energy that corresponds to velocity $v+dv$, with $$\tag{1}dE = d\left(\frac{1}{2}mv^2\right) = mv dv$$ Don't think of $dE$ *and* $dv$ as "fixed" simultaneously: if you fix one, the other one is immediately fixed via Eq (1) above.

Comment: Thank you, this leads to a 2nd question; does integration actually go in steps of _fixed_ intervals regardless of integrating with $dv$ or $dE$? If yes, then how is it possible that $$\int_a^bh(E)dE=\int_{\sqrt{2a/m}}^{\sqrt{2b/m}}f(v)dv$$ Because we just agreed that at each step, one interval should vary based on the other fixed interval. For example, keeping $dv$ fixed would make $dE$ vary with $v$ according to $dE=mvdv$. And yet, integrating with both intervals _fixed simultaneously_ would give an equal outcome, how?

Comment: @Phy The number of molecules with energies between $a$ and $b$ is exactly the same as the number of molecules with velocities $\sqrt{2a/m}$ and $\sqrt{2b/m}$. This is the equality between the integrals you have written. Are you asking why these two numbers are the same? It's because "particles with energy larger than $a$ "is equivalent to "particles with velocity larger than $\sqrt{2a/m}$"; and "particles with energy less than $b$" is equivalent to "particles with "velocity less than $\sqrt{2b/m}$".

Comment: Thanks. I think my question is more of a calculus issue. For example $$\int_a^{a+mvdv}h(E)dE=h(a)mvdv$$ I'd assume here $dE$ is fixed during integration and $dE<<mvdv$? If yes, then this implies $$\frac{P(E+dE)-P(E)}{dE}=\frac{P(E+mvdv)-P(E)}{mvdv}$$ But I can only grasp this equation if $h(E)$ is constant for each integer $dE$ step _within_ the interval $mvdv$. If $h(E)$ differs with each $dE$ step, then this equation is impossible. So does $h(E)$ differ or does it stay constant with each $dE$ step within the interval mvdv?

Comment: Why do you write $dE \ll mv dv$? It should be $dE = mv dv$. This equation links $dE$ to $dv$ so that both differentials describe exactly the same interval. Here is another example: Say $L$ is the side of a square and $A=L^2$ is its area. The number of squares whose sides fall  in the range $(L_1,L_2)=(1,2)$ is the same as the number of squares whose area falls in $(A_1,A_2)=(1,4)$. Here $\delta L=1$ and $\delta A = 3$. If you keep making the intervals smaller and smaller you will get $\delta A\to 2L\delta L$, which says $$dA = d(L^2) = 2 L dL$$.

Comment: You found my confusion. My root issue is the size of dE that is used for integration. I think an answer to the following questions would help me.

1. During integration, is the value of dE kept constant? I.e. does the integrand go in steps fixed dE steps?
2. If yes, then the dE used during integration is not equal to mvdv because mvdv varies with v (and thus E). How then is dE=mvdv when there's an integration involved? (like in my previous equation)

Comment: $dE$ and $dv$ are differentials, I don't think of them as constants. Their meaning in this problem is this: if $dE$ and $dv$ are both small enough, then the interval $dE$ contains the same number of elements as $mv dv$. Of course the differentials $dE$ and $dv$ are not equal, but notice that $dv$ must be multiplied by $mv$ to give us the correct number of elements. That's what we mean when we say $dE = mv dv$. To summarize: when the interval $dv$ is multiplied by $mv$ it contains the same number of elements as interval $dE$.

Comment: Okay, but how does an integration "know" that dE=mvdv so it changes that interval dE accordingly during integration? There's a "v" in mvdv so dE must increase in size at higher v values.

Comment: We construct the functions $f(v)$ and $h(E)$  so that this requirement is built in. This is accomplished by setting $$f(v) dv = h(E) dE$$ which says, whether you integrate function $f$ or function $h$ between equivalent limits you will get the same answer.